# Why has my keyboard stopped sending Super_L for the windows key in X?

Tags: linux-mint, x11, keyboard, xfce

I'm on Linux Mint 20 with XFCE as my WM. I do have an .Xmodmap file that consists of the following:

```
keycode 166 = 0x0000
keycode 167 = 0x0000
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 = Escape
keycode 135 = Super_R
```

The first two are to disable the Back/Forward buttons under my space bar on my keyboard. The last line is to make the context menu key become a Super key.

My problem though is that that the windows/start key on the left side of my keyboard is not working as it should. When I run xev to check what event it sends, it doesn't send a Super_L, it does something strange as shown below:

```
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

It was working before, but I've been playing around with window managers and wonder what I might have done to cause this to happen. I tried changing the keyboard settings so that my keyboard model was specifically a Microsoft Natural Ergo 4000, which is what I have, but that doesn't change this behavior.

One other weird thing is that if I try to change a window manager hotkey mapping in XFCE, when it gives me the option to detect and set the hotkey for a function, it does detect pressing the Windows key as "Super", but then trying to use the Windows key as super for the hotkey function doesn't work, which I find very strange.

I've tried restarting, unplugging and repluging in the keyboard and using a different keyboard, all with the same results.  I even tried creating a new clean user and using XFCE and it happens on that user as well. So it's more like a system level problem than an individual XFCE config problem.

Any ideas as to what might be wrong or other ways I could diagnose this?

Comment: I may have fixed this problem for myself and I think it's a bug in XFCE's default setup.  I just ran "xfconf-query --channel xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p '/xfwm4/custom/Super_L' --reset" to remove a command key shortcut that should have opened the start menu, but doesn't. My left Super key works now and generates the proper keypress release events.